# Abstract property in class cannot be accessed in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have recently migrated my angular app to ng7 and upgraded the typescript to 3.1.3. On compiling the code i am getting the error. Could somebody tell me what the problem is ?

Abstract property 'uploadType' in class 'BaseUploadComponent' cannot be accessed in the constructor.

```
 export abstract class BaseUploadComponent extends ReactiveComponent implements OnInit {
        accept = '*.*';

        showPopup = false;
        popMsg = 'Do you want to reupload file!';
        description: string;
        uploadFile: Dto.FileDescription;
        @ViewChild('form') rootForm: ElementRef;
        newUpload: Dto.UploadInfo = { type: this.uploadType, originalFileName: null, ident: this.ident };
        previousFiles: Dto.FileDescription[];

        protected ready = new Rx.Subject<void>();
        protected abstract get ident(): string;
        protected abstract get uploadType(): Dto.UploadType;
        private rawData: string | ArrayBuffer;

        constructor(
            private _admin: Proxy.AdminProxy,
            private _alertService: AlertService,
            private _translate: TranslateService
        ) {
            super();
            this.ready.subscribe(() => this.refreshList());
        }


        private refreshList() {
            this._admin.listVersions({ type: this.uploadType, ident: this.ident }).uiSignal('files list').subscribe(ret => this.previousFiles = ret.data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would move that to `ngOnInit` and keep the constructor as empty as possible.

Comment: Are you using the AOT compiler? I actually had trouble with abstract component classes throwing errors at build time. It wouldn't let me declare them at a module level, and not declaring them gave me a different error.

Comment: I m not using the AOT compier and moving that to ngOnInit isnt helping either

Comment: it compiled , If i remove the abstract keyword from  the property and return. Not sure if that is correct protected  get ident(): string { return;};
    protected  get uploadType(): Dto.UploadType {return;};